# TypeInitializationException was unhandled - OpenNLP using IKVM

Tags: c#, java, ikvm

I'm using opennlp tool in C# using IKVM. I wrote the following code:

```
string modelpath = @"D:\models\en-sent.bin";
java.io.FileInputStream modelInpStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(modelpath);
SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelInpStream);
SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);
```

but it caused a TypeInitializationException in the line:

```
SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelInpStream);
```

the Exception message:

> TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   The type initializer for 'java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets' threw an exception.

I have added IKVM Charsets dll but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll files are in your application bin directory. Visual Studio does not always copy all referenced assemblies (if they aren't "used").

Another suggestion is to try to print the full exception (from the Java perspective). That goes something like this:

```
using ikvm.extensions;  // make the Exception extension methods available

try {
  ...
} catch (Exception x) {
  x.printStackTrace();
}
```

That should give more information about the underlying cause of the TypeInitializationException.

Comment: What version of IKVM are you using and what is your system locale setting?

Comment: IKVM 7.2.4630.5 and its English (United States)

Comment: Hmm. Can you try catching the exception and then printing it as a Java exception? I'll edit my answer to add that suggestion.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for 
_at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream..ctor(InputStream in)
   at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel..ctor(String componentName, InputStream in)
   at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel..ctor(InputStream in)
   at Parser.MainPage.sentDetect_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\MuhammadKashif\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Parser\Parser\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 55_

Comment: No, you really need the full Java stack trace. It includes the original exception (a TypeInitializationException is never the cause of the problem, it is the result of an exception that happens while the type initializer was running).